# Como fazer Chaves Estrangeiras utilizando Migrations Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, migrations

Estou tentando relacionar um campo com outro utilizando as migrations desse modo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém ao fazer a chave estrangeira na migrations desta forma:

**Migration Permission:**

```
  Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('id');

          $table->index('user_id');

          $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Migration User:**

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('id', 100)->primary();

        // Código Omitido...
    });

    Schema::table('permissions', function($table) {
         $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
     });
```

**Erro que Recebo no terminal:**

> `Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'user_id' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table`permissions`add index`permissions_user_id_index`(`user_id`))
>        1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'user_id' doesn't exist in table")      D:\Infinity\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php : 458
>       2   PDOStatement::execute()      D:\Infinity\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php : 458`

Comment: a sua migration está faltando o campo `user_id`? o erro apresentando é esse ... só tem esse código?

Comment: além desse problema, acredito que a relação poderia ser muitos para muitos!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Não está faltando o user_Id ele está declarado nas permissions. Só esses códigos mesmo

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Mas não é essa relação que está sendo feita?

Comment: A relação me parece pelo desenho, 1 para muitos! é bom você colocar a migration corretamente, porque, me parece que tem código dentro do lugar errado isso também causa problemas na geração do modelo fisico.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Eu fiz duas migrations uma da tabela Permissions e a outra da Users, na migration da Users é feita a relação pois preciso das duas tabelas feitas para ter a relação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você esqueceu de definir a coluna `user_id`.

Note que você apenas definiu `user_id` como indice, mas não criou a coluna antes disso.

```
  Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('id');

          $table->index('user_id');

          $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Faça a seguinte substituição:

```
  Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('id');

          $table->integer('user_id');
          $table->index('user_id');

          $table->timestamps();
    });
```